# Installed New CHFP120DF breaker, and it is displaying ground fault without connection

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

I just installed a new Eaton CHFP120DF breaker, and it is displaying ground fault (LED blinks 5 times) without being attached to load neutral and power wires. I understand this may not be a defective breaker since the 5 flash code may be from testing at the factory.

Is there a way to erase this code from the breaker before attaching it to the circuit?

And, am I to assume the breaker is not defective because it didn’t trip, but just shows the ground fault code?

Comment: Do the breaker instructions say how to clear it? IIRC it goes away after some number of power cycles.

Answer (score 1):

According to the instructions, it should stop blinking the fault code after 30 repeats. If yours doesn't stop after 30 repeats, it might be defective.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s information I received from Eaton tech support:

When you first power a breaker up, even with no load it will blink a pattern (typically what was tested last in the plant).  Also if you go through the sequence to obtain the trip code (pressing and hold test, while turning on the breaker) it will blink a pattern.  But as long as the breaker didn't trip before it blinked then it's not an issue with the breaker.  There isn't any way to clear the last trip code, that will always be stored in the breaker, so if power is lost and then restored or the trip code is pulled up it will show a blink pattern.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to report your findings!